# Clear numerical Textbox and send Value - C# Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, textbox, numeric, sendkeys

I have a numerical Textfield.
I can fill this Textfield with Sendkeys ...

This is the HTML Code.

```html
HTML-Code:

<input class="form-control busy-disabled" 
id="entry-lots" 
type="number" 
value="1" min="0.01" max="20" step="0.01">
```

But first i want to clear this Textfield. If i send a *.Clear() it will result in a new value "0.01" ... whatever was inside before.

My Code is:

```html
IWebElement element = webdriver.FindElement(By.Id("entry-lots"));
element.Click();
element.Clear();
element.SendKeys("0.02");
```

This short lines will result in the Value "0.01002" and not in "0.02" as i need.

Any Ideas to help me out?
If interesting: I am using a Windows-Forms Program.

#Edit 1: Start

The Webpage is:
https://eas.forexsb.com/

Navigate in the blue Top Line to "Generator" and switch there to "Reactor".
Down in the "Reactor" switch to "2. Strategy properties".

The Field "Entry lots" will give my problem.

#Edit 1: End

Comment: I reproduced your example and i take the 0.02 as input value

Comment: Yes, my example Code works normally fine ...
I don´t know what this Webpage do, but as said with the Clear the Value will reset to 0.01 ...
I have absolute no idea what i can do ... Also no idea what additional info i can find into the Page to clearyfy this.

But thank you very much for your try and also feedback.

Comment: Share the actual webpage if you want

Comment: I edited my original Post just parallel with it.
Thank you

Comment: You definitly found my point. Thank you for your time to trigger me on the right way.
I have to check my code before.
Thank you very, very much

It is not allowed for me to give your answer a positive up arrow until now. So feel like i have placed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code you should get the expexted results

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

var driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://eas.forexsb.com/");

var menu = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id='acquisition-toggle']"));
menu.Click();

var reactor = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@data-name='Reactor']"));
reactor.Click();

var collapse = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@href='#collapse2']"));
collapse.Click();

var input = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@id='entry-lots']"));
input.Click();
input.Clear();
input.SendKeys("0.02");
```

Comment: Thank you for your testing and this peace of code.
I tested it and your Code work absolute fine ... 
It is absolutely nothing with the number Textbox, as expected!

Ok, that was absolutely not in my mind. But it is as it is ...
I have to check all around tomorrow for myself^^
THANK you very much to clearify this point for me. I never thought of any other problem in the code, as everything previous worked fine and this few lines looked well.
Only the Textbox looks different as i know from the past.

Great job = Thank you (Answer Accept will follow soon)